# Why was this question about desoldering a power jack migrated?

Tags: discussion

I saw this interesting question  https://superuser.com/q/1046262 about desoldering a power jack, but was surprised to see it on Superuser.SE rather than on Electronics.SE. Further investigation showed it *was* originally asked here but then migrated.

The meat of the question has basically nothing to do with computers. It is about desoldering a multi-lead discrete component. From experience I agree with the top answer (cut the defective component to pieces and extract the leads one by one.) I cannot find a similar question by searching for "desoldering" and I think it would be a useful question on this site.

I also think it would be more appropriate to Electronics.SE than Superuser.SE.
Arguably questions such as [Desoldering from a graphics card](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/18130/50922) have *more* reason to be migrated to superuser.SE, yet they are still here.

So, after receiving many good answers here, why was it migrated from here to Superuser.SE?

Comment: I'm going to flag the question for an incorrect migration and hope someone else picks it up.

Comment: @Mikey  From beginning, you doubted whether or not you have posted to the right place.  You've got good answers.  I would imagine that for you it doesn't make a difference whether the question gets parked: here or there.

Comment: At this point, I'm wishing you'd have left it the hell alone.

Comment: @Mikey  I too wish to leave it alone: on SuperUser.

Comment: Question was VTC by multiple users on SU, and Migration rejected, so its back on here. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/219621/desoldering-a-tricky-dc-jack Now we need to vote to reopen, ***AS ITS A VALID ON TOPIC QUESTION HERE***

Comment: Eventually reopened by community vote.

Comment: I go with @MikeyT.K. I dont understand whats the point of discussion because it is clearly an electronics question! Every computer chip is an electronics thing.... should all things related to it be migrated there?

Answer (score -25):

Because repair questions are off-topic for EE.SE .

The O.P. got a bunch of excellent answers.  Good for him.  But EE.SE gets a piece of search engine bait for *"laptop connector repair"* queries.  It's better for everyone if the questions sits on SuperUser and attracts such traffic over to SuperUser.

> [...] Arguably questions such as [Desoldering from a graphics card](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/18130/50922) have *more* reason to be migrated to superuser.SE, yet they are still here.

That graphics card question is from an old era when standards weren't as high.  StackExchange doesn't allow to migrate questions that are older than 90 days.

Comment: Generally,  questions about rework techniques to carry out a specific repair task have been considered on topic here.

Comment: [Yes.](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/160172/cutting-off-metal-anchor-legs-on-an-hdmi-port-or-metal-connector-what-to-use)  SuperUser should also have some of this, considering that the question is about repair of a laptop.

Comment: The fact that it's a laptop is immaterial to the fact that it is a completely electronics-technique question. It could be quite literally any piece of gear that uses DC current, and the same question and answers would be valuable.

Comment: Furthermore, you should probably burn the laptop tag if you feel this way.

Comment: And repair questions are not off topic. That question goes into depth on what they tried and why/how, which is what repair questions need to be on topic here. But it's not a repair question. They arnt asking why the device isn't working or blindly troubleshooting.

Comment: @Passerby  If we open the gates for repair questions, we'll get swamped.  EE.SE is too competent for repair question.

Comment: EE.SE is already open to repair questions of sufficient quality. As it specifically states, the asker has to have a decent understanding of the underlying circuit. Questions like "my tv broke, how do I fix it" are bad ***AND*** off topic, but questions like "I tried x y and z on this circuit, which typically work because of a b and c, but isn't"  Are valid. This is the latter, even if you consider it a repair question.

Comment: @Passerby  Do you want web searches for "replace laptop connector" to lead to EE.SE?  Yes or No.

Comment: @NickAlexeev any web search for that would lead to a single, high quality post. That's the point.

Comment: @Passerby  Is that a *yes* or a *no*?  (Not to mention that your so called point is an obvious.  It's a truism.)

Comment: @NickAlexeev Since when do concerns other than "is X on topic for the site" determine whether a question is allowed or not? Furthermore, nothing in the tour suggests this question is OT where it was asked. Pretty much everyone posting here is in disagreement with your action. I'd suggest taking that criticism onboard instead of ignoring it?